# How do I go about manipulating this summation equation to solve it?

Tags: algorithms, summation, recurrence-relations, logarithms, recursion

In my textbook, *Introduction to Algorithms*, the following is shown:

[image]

And I believe I understand that. However, I have a similar equation to the one on the first line, but instead of $(\frac{3}{16})^i$, I have $\log_2({\frac{n}{2^i})}$.

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\log_2{n-1}} \log({\frac{n}{2^i}})$

I'm really confused where I'd go with that difference. How do I deal with the fact it's a logarithm in order to get it down to solving for big-O?

Comment: Well, the idea here is to estimate the partial sum of a geometric series by its limit (in this case, it exists because $3/16 < 1$). But, in your case, I don't think it is possible if I understand what you're saying: 
$$\sum_{i=0}^k [\log_2(n) - i] = (k+1) \log_2(n) - \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$ is not the partial sum of any convergent series. However, it is not hard to write this sum explicitly and the explicit expression is actually pretty (not at all messy!)

Comment: This is what I have: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\log_2{n-1}} \log({\frac{n}{2^i}})$

Comment: So, yes, in your case $k = \log_2(n) - 1$; I hope you followed my remark above.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to what happened to the $\lg(\frac{n}{2^i})$

Comment: I have used the fact that, for $u, v > 0$, $\log(u/v) = \log(u) - \log(v)$ to simplify that sum.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but could you just explain how you got that above equation there? Summations really are my weakness. I don't understand where the stuff like (k+1) came from.

Answer (score 0):

You can bound the sum quite coarsely by $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\log_2{n-1}} \log({\frac{n}{2^i}}) \lt (\log_2 n)(\log n)=O((\log n)^2) $ which is dominated by the other term

Comment: How did you get to $(\log_2{n})(\log(n))$?

Comment: I took the number of terms times the greatest one.

Comment: How did you calculate the greatest one?

Comment: There are $\log_2$ terms being added.  The first one is $\log n$, and all the rest are smaller because the argument of the log is smaller.  The total is then less than the product of those.  Note that $n$ is fixed in the sum-t doesn't vary between the terms.